# FileZilla tranfer files between linux and windows machine basic tutorial

Tags: windows, linux, file-transfer, filezilla

I have a Windows machine, from which I want to transfer files to a Linux machine. Can someone briefly explain to me how to I use FileZilla for that? Do I have to have server running on the Windows machine? How will they talk to each other? How do I connect them? I know this must be somewhere in the tutorials, but I am chasing a major deadline at work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a FTP server on the linux server to use filezilla with it. Alternately you can run filezilla server on the windows box, and use the CLI FTP software on the linux box to pull in files - that's quite overcomplex though.

However if its a linux server, arn't sure if the linux box has a STP server, and you have SSH access, you can use SFTP or SCP to transfer files over to it instead.I tend to prefer [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) (there's other ftp and SCP clients, but its the one i like the most).

```
      Client System +-----------------------> Server
   +-------------------------------+      +----------------------+
   |  Running FTP client           |      |   Running FTP server |
   |-------------------------------|      |----------------------|
   |                               |      |Needs account set up  |
   |  username                     |      |on FTP server         |
   |  password                     |      |                      |
   |  FTP server hostname/address  |      |                      |
   |  Needs port open      (21)    |      |                      |
   +-------------------------------+      +----------------------+
   +-----------------------------------+  +------------------------+
   | SFTP/SCP - Winscp or cyberduck    |  | Running SSH server     |
   |-----------------------------------|  |------------------------|
   | Needs account on server           |  |uses user account       |
   | Password                          |  |encrypted/secure        |
   | Account needs access to directory |  |                        |
   | needs port 22                     |  |                        |
   +-----------------------------------+  +------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe FileZilla is a FTP client, so it connects to a ftp server. Meaning if you are transfering from the windows machine then the linux machine needs to be running a ftp server to which you can connect.

Comment: But FileZilla server only runs on Windows

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to setup a ftp server, but if you are going to try and transfer from one computer to another with a ftp client, then one computer (the remote one if one is remote) needs to be running ftp server software.

Comment: FileZilla is the name of both a ftp client and a ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

You must install ftp server in linux:

```
yum install vsftpd
```

make changes in configuration file of ftp server in linux machine:

```
vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

anonymas_enable=YES
Listen=YES
```

make sure to remove from below 2 files:

```
vim/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
vim/etc/vsftpd/user_list
```

restart ftp server:

```
systemctl restart vsftpd
```

======================================

On Windows machine:

download filezilla app

put your ftp server (Linux machine) IP address

enter username: root

enter password: root's password

enter ftp port no. : mostly port number 20 or 21.

and there you go...this should make the connection for file transfer from Windows to Linux successfull.